What does "ab!" mean in Markov algorithm?
I can't find information neither understand what does ab! mean, to be accurate - what does the "!" mean in the Markov algorithm? Is it just a sign more like an element of an output alphabet, or it has the other meaning?
I have a task wherr I have to write a scheme for the given word baba and result for it must be ab!, so now I'm trying to figure out how should I write down the scheme.

What algorithm are you talking about? is this from a textbook exercise? This needs more context, otherwise its too ambiguous, imo--if $a$ and $b$ are numbers it could mean factorial, the author could just be emphasizing something, or $!$ could be an element of the alphabet.

Most of the time, $n!$ means $1\cdot2\cdot\cdots\cdot n,$ and the standard order of operations would mean $ab!=a\cdot(b!).$ But it really depends on the context.

@ThomasAndrews the thing is, there's not much context in the textbook task. it's only said "some normal Markov algorithm over the alphabet Σ = {a, b} when applied to the input word baba produces the result ab!", so that's why I'm a bit confused by this

Well, that is enough to discount the numeiric meaning, since $a,b$ are letters, not numbers. @stephan

If you can't give the full text, people will waste a lot of time. The $!$ might just be punctuation - the writers might really be excited by what they are saying.

Given the alphabet, $\Sigma,$ does not contain the character $!$, the writer can't mean the output is literally $ab!$ So I can only guess that the exclamation mark just has its usual meaning. However, I can't think of why they would find what you've quoted is exciting, since we can write a Markov process which always outputs "$ab$". Can you tell us where this comes from?

this is from my textbook my prof gives to us, we don't know the origins. ig $!$ is not exctening, since there's text for the next condition and the only punctuation used between the two parts is a simple comma.
